# One single delete statement query takes lots of time?

Tags: sql

For example:

`delete from dk_lor where cyt=9 and df=6 and l_t='S'`

And the table `dk_lor` is also an independent one. I haven't used any kind of trigger to it and also having index for the columns but still it takes much time to delete the records.

Could any one advise me what to do now?

---

"Independent One" means neither other table depends upon it nor it depends to others(No Referential Integrity concept).

Comment: Add a composed index on `(cyt,df,l_t)`

Comment: How many rows in the table? How many rows get deleted? How many time is it currently taking?

Comment: Please clarify, "independent one".

Comment: Thats a basic query. IN case its taking much time,got something to do with either your table relationship or PC memory usage I guess!

Comment: How may time do you need by executing `select count(*) from dk_lor where cyt=9 and df=6 and l_t='S'`?

Comment: can you post the execution plan?

Comment: Hi Nadeem, It's Oracle 11gR2 database.

Comment: "Independent One" means rather the other tables is depends to it nor it depends to other table.(No referential Integrity Concept).

Comment: @DebashisKhatai Comment with `@username` to inform us in time.

Comment: I have 3indexes for the table dk_lor.But how could I check which index is used by this query ?